# What event fires when a UISlider is dragged all the way to the end?

Tags: ios, uikit, xamarin

I've got a UISlider in my View.

```csharp
_seekBar = new UISlider
{
    MinValue = 0,
    Continuous = false,
    AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
};
_seekBar.TouchDown += OnTouchDown;
_seekBar.TouchDragInside += OnDragInside;
_seekBar.ValueChanged += OnValueChanged;
```

I've setup the three events as follows.

```csharp
private void OnTouchDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // pause the watcher when you touch down
    _audioPlayerService.Pause();
}

private void OnDragInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // basically updates the number next to the slider as you drag
    _viewModel.CurrentPositionMsec = (int)_seekBar.Value;
}

private void OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.UserSeekPosition = (int)_seekBar.Value;

    if (_viewModel.SeekToCommand.CanExecute())
        _viewModel.SeekToCommand.Execute(_viewModel);

    _audioPlayerService.Start();
}
```

*note: The watcher basically watches the Audio Player and reports back the progress.*

The problem I'm experiencing is that if I drag the slider all the way to the end (far right), even without releasing anything, I start getting weird behavior.

- Attempting to re-drag doesn't stop the watcher
- The Slider starts jumping between my thumb position and the watched current progress.
- Audio stutters and jumps to the end of the track.

I don't want ANYTHING to happen when I slide my thumb to the end unless I release the slider.

*note: If I don't seek all the way to the end, everything works exactly as expected*

**What event fires when a UISlider is dragged all the way to the end?**

Answer (score 2):

"I don't want ANYTHING to happen when I slide my thumb to the end unless I release the slider"

Do this. It will only fire once the touch is released.

```
_seekBar.continuous = NO;
```

Comment: yeah if you look in the first code block, I have that. It's C# since I'm using Xamarin.

Comment: I don't think there is a any method that checks to see if slider has reached the end/max value. What you can do is check if OnValueChanged value of the slider is less than the max specified